# Image appears stretched on secondary monitor?

Tags: resolution, external-display, aspect-ratio

I have a Samsung R522 notebook and a Medion(?) TV, and an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4330.

The problem is, when I plug in the TV into my notebook, the resolution changes on both the notebook and the TV. The resolution on the TV is now stretched and I cannot fix it. Help would be **VERY** appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing the same image on both screens?  If so your external monitor is in "clone" mode and the resolution chosen is one compatible to both displays.  If you want different resolutions on each, and different images too, then you need to make the external monitor "extended" mode.  Then set its resolution to its native mode.  That will give you a properly proportioned image.

Answer (score 2):

When using the ***duplicate*** mode, the resolution will be the same on all monitors, so it must be the smallest resolution of the screens. That means if the monitors have different aspect ratios then the images will be stretched on at least one monitor. You may want to change to ***extend mode*** by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> if you're using Windows